# powershell script to set property PriorityClass of ms access

Tags: powershell, ms-access, automation

I have the following PS script that runs 25 separate Access db's in an automation. This runs once every hour. I have the common problem of databases "freezing" for extended periods of time. If I am watching live, and have Task Manager open, I can elevate the priority of MSAccess and the database runs quickly. I would like to add a line of code that would elevate the priority of MS Access each time that I call it. ( Variable $Owner truncated to 3 for brevity)

```
# Run Merge Database on all Owner groups
$Owner = "Beach", "Bennett", "Burger"
foreach ($element in $Owner) 
{ # BEGIN "foreach" LOOP
# Create variable with directory of Target file
$OwnerPath = "E:\ServerFolders\Ops\$element\$element-Merge.accdb"

# Remove # below to see Directory variables
Write-Output $OwnerPath

# start Access
$access = New-Object -comobject Access.Application

#make it visible (just to check what is happening)
$access.Visible = $true

#access the Application object and run a macro
$access.OpenCurrentDatabase($OwnerPath)


} # END "foreach"
```

Comment: Any reason not using just one DB, that does the same or even better do everything in a Powershell Script.

Comment: There are a couple of reasons: 1) The database would be too large. I complile 1-3 databases into each of these DB's referenced. I have had memory exceeded errors in the past when the date range was just a couple of years longer on only 3 databases. 2) These DB's are used as source tables for Excel pivot tables. The source tables are included in the Excel file so that users can drill down on the data. If it was one big database that would be a monster of an included table.

Comment: What kind of data produces that size? Access is a great RAD Frontend, but the database skills are limited. Use a professional RDBMS like MS SQL-Server, MySQL or Postgre  instead and link your excel files to that.Back to the process priority. I found [this](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=235076) solution for vba and some other links for ps, all untested: http://monadblog.blogspot.com/2006/03/msh-how-to-change-processs-priority.html , https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/89548-set-cpu-process-priority-applications-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly but you can do something like the following

```
$PIDS_Before = Get-Process | ?{ $_.Name -like "iexplore*"} | select id, Name
$IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application
sleep -Seconds 5
$Pid_After = Get-Process | ?{$_.Name -like "iexplore*"} | select id, Name
Compare-Object $PIDS_Before $Pid_After | select -ExpandProperty InputObject | %{
    $process = Get-Process -Id $_.Id
    $process.PriorityClass = "High"
}
```

The real area that you need to reach is the **PriorityClass** in a Process object
The problem is getting the PID from a COM Object. If you can get that then you can get the process with get-process -id $PIDHERE

the reason for the sleep (which is really really hate) is you need to wait for the object to load. Sometimes 5 seconds isn't enough and you may need longer.

The accepted values for the priority class are
**Idle, BelowNormal, Normal, AboveNormal, High, RealTime**

Comment: Thank you for that idea. I played with it for a while, using the as-written code, and trying to modify it for MS Access. I could not get either to work. I kept getting an error from the Compare-Object.

Comment: what error did you get? Could you edit your posta and show the code you used with the information i provided?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
$job = "msaccess.exe"
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "CommandLine LIKE '%$job%'" | select ProcessId | %{ $process = Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId; $process.PriorityClass = "High" }
```

This snippet is very useful for set priorities in bulk mode:

```
$job = "scheduled.bat"
while (1) {
  Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "CommandLine LIKE '%$job%'" | select ProcessId | %{ $process = Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId; $process.PriorityClass = "High" }
  "sleeping"
  sleep (30)
}
```